# How to display array images in thumbnail in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to i phone programming.

Can anybody tell me how I can display document directory folder images in 4by4 thumbnail like a photo gallery? All images are stored in an array.

Comment: I have store all images in array.Inside array all image path is there,using this array how can i display images in thumbnail.

Comment: If you had searched properly you could have found this [**sample code PhotoScroller by Apple**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080) easily. -1 for no efforts. Read [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

->you must add scrollview and then connect IBOutlet

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

int nLastYPos = 0;

 for (int i=0; i<[arrImages count]; i++)
    {
        UIView *Viewthumbnail = [[UIView alloc] init];
        Viewthumbnail.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString StringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]]]];
        Viewthumbnail.frame = CGRectMake(4+(i%4)*44,5+(i/4)*44, 42, 42);
        [scroll addSubview: Viewthumbnail];
        nLastYPos = btnthumbnail.frame.origin.y+44;
        [Viewthumbnail release];
    }
    if(nLastYPos>280)
        scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width,nLastYPos);
}
```

Comment: hey where i have use this condition

Comment: where you want to show thumbnailView images?

Comment: i want to display images in view

Comment: in which device you want to show thumbnailimage ipad or iphone

Comment: i want to display in iphone.like same as photo gallery album

Comment: what is your xcode version? if your xcode version 4.5 or above UICollectionView is the best way do this..

Comment: I am using Mac10.6.8 version Xcode 4,IOS 5.0

Comment: just now posted updated code i have checked it this code working fine for me..

Comment: hey this code is show some error.In this line

Comment: [Viewthumbnail setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString StringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[arrImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: sorry last time i forget to edit now check it

Comment: Hey then also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by create subViews with width and height u need then add it to superview "scrollView"

```
-(void) createGridView:(NSMutilbeArray *)array{
for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
{
  UIView *temp=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,wi,hi)];//UIImageView
  [scrollView addSubView:temp];
}
}
```

u can give each view tag to handle touch action by `sender.tag`

Comment: Thanks for giving replay.By usign this code,how to display in 4 by 4 thumbnail image

Comment: it is depend on view width and height. by the way what do u mean 4x4 ?? 4 image in the view ???

Comment: no like photo gallery each row we will 4 images na like that i want

Comment: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rephotocollectioncontroller

Comment: the width for the device is 320px/4 an u have the width for each uiimageview that u will add as subview and it is the same for height :)